# Smileys in EditText, With FromHtml, Showing symbol instead image

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-edittext

I am trying to insert image into `EditText`, My IDs of the images are stored in Integer List...
and I show a `GridView` that contain all the smiles and When the user select smile I use the method :

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
```

and pass the index to the List of the IDs, then get the ID, and Post it to FromHtml :

here the code:

```
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            int p;
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                  p=i;
                   Html.ImageGetter imgg= new Html.ImageGetter() {
                    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                        Log.d("SOMAA","source= "+source);
                        Log.d("SOMAA","Arrived index = "+p);
                        Log.d("SOMAA","ID = "+SmilesList[p]);
                        Drawable   d =   Massenger_frag.this.getResources().getDrawable(SmilesList[p]);

                        if (d != null) {
                            d.setBounds(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth(),d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                        }
                        Log.d("SOMAA","d = "+d);

                        return d;

                    }
                };
                indexSmile=i;
                Log.d("SOMAA","index = " + i+ " OR "+ indexSmile);
         //       ImageView imv= (ImageView) view.findViewById(SmilesList[indexSmile]);
                Spanned smiletxt = Html.fromHtml("<img src='" + getResources().getDrawable(SmilesList[indexSmile])+"'/>",imgg,null);
                Log.d("SOMAA","Smile text= "+smiletxt);
               EditText msgt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.MessageInMessanger);
               String str = msgt.getText().toString();

                str+= smiletxt;
                msgt.setText(str);
            }
        });
```

the problem is: 
instead of the smile I see the symbole [obj] in the EditText....

Why?  and how may I solve this issue!

Comment: Have you tried `text.setCompoundDrawables()` or ImageSpan instead of html?

Comment: No, But I found that this way(that I uses) Is sample and clear, but I wondered why does it show [obj] symbol instead the smily (i.e : Smyily01.png